# Display image for a Yes or No value in mysql table display

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where one of the values is either Yes or No. I would like to have the value represented by an image according to the value. Table is also using pagination and am using code to alternate row color. Code:

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM txmit ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $start_from, 25";

$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM txmit"); 
$number=mysql_num_rows($query);

`while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($rs_result)){

// If $color==1 table row color = #747E80
if($color==1){
echo "<tr bgcolor='#DBDBDB'>
<td>.$rows['pid']."</td><td>".$rows['sent']."</td></tr> 
?>
```

The $rows['sent'] is the Yes or No value...how do I get it to display image based on Yes or No value.
thanks

Comment: I didnt include remaining code for 2nd row color etc..obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
echo "<img src=img/" . $rows['sent'] == 'Yes' ? 'yes.png' : 'no.png' . ">";
```

If they're really just `Yes` and `No` you could also use:

```
echo "<img src=img/" . $rows['sent'] . ".png>"; // Yes.png or No.png
```

If the image path gets a bit longer I'd agree with Blazemonger's comment and make it more readable:

```
echo '<img src=very/long/image/path/';

if($rows['sent'] == 'Yes') {
    echo 'yes.png >';
} else {
    echo 'no.png >';
}
```

Comment: I would prefer the Boolean conditional to be on a separate line preceding, just to make the code more readable.

Comment: hmm, not working, it may be my level of knowledge. Does the code get placed between the <td> for that specific column , do I need to re-echo? sorry for being ignorant.  Thanks

Comment: It would be `<td><img src=img/" . $rows['sent'] . ".png></td>` then

Comment: thank you, first time poster, long time browser. Thanks again